# How to make dropdownlist as Readonly Field In Infopath 2010

Tags: infopath

How to make `dropdownlist` as `Readonly` Field in Infopath 2010.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT: made solution 1 solution 2 and add a new solution and made that solution 1**

**Solution 1**

- Select the control
- The "Control Properties" tab should light up and you should see "Manage Rules"
- Click the New button on Manage Rules and select Formatting

**Solution 2**

You can use conditional formatting to disable any control (including drop down lists). To set your control to always be disabled do the following:

1. Right click on your control and select Conditional Formatting...
2. Click Add...
3. In the leftmost dropdown select The expression
4. type true() in the text field (this tells InfoPath to always apply this formatting)
5. Check the Disable this control checkbox.
6. Click OK and OK.

Note: You will need to do this for each of your drop down lists.

Hope this helps.

**PK**

Comment: i don't see "Conditional Formatting" when i right click DropDownList. I use info path 2010.

Comment: I still don't see Format - conditional formatting. you can see my picture to here: http://maxup.vn/hinh-anh/all/fxivqbf4a5kjr0b/ please help me

Comment: ok no problem i think you are in the wrong section. press alt+o
the letter o to open up the format menu then conditional formatting is right there.

Comment: i will update the post for you right away. this should definitely work now

Answer (score 2):

Its is very Simple to HIDE or make a field Read Only

1. All the other Fields can be made READ ONLY just by Right Clicking on
   the Required Field and u FIND a DISPLAY tab in the pop-up " Check
   the "READ ONLY" and UNCHECK Remaining options !!
2. For DATE and DROP DOWN Fields

Click on the FIELD --> Go to Manage Rules ---> Add RULE --> condition --> select "the expression" and type true() in the next box !! click OK
 Later, Check on the " Disable the Control "